# Equivalent of bash command **time**

Tags: r, time

How do I time the running duration of R scripts?

I basically want an equivalent to the bash command **time**.

Comment: The function you are looking for is `system.time()`.

Comment: You may also want to try searching here: entering `[r] time` in the search bar at the top right would get you results (with the R tag here) that lead to `system.time()` rather quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `system.time`, or take a look at the `microbenchmark` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `benchmark` function from `rbenchmark` package. See helpfile [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbenchmark/rbenchmark.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a complicated script that can't be evaluated by `system.time()`, try:

```
start_time = proc.time()
<your script here>
end_time = proc.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

Obviously you need to run lines 1-3 as close to each other as possible.

There are some examples [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-July/247399.html).